# undefined reference to `zgesvd_' - BLAS issues in C compilation

Tags: blas

I am having an issue with the LAPACK/BLAS libraries when compiling a C code that needs them.

The issues are, when I run "make", I get:

```
file.c:(.text+0x1c41): undefined reference to `zgesvd_'
file.c:(.text+0x1c9c): undefined reference to `zgetrf_'
../file.a(SpatialOrientation.o): In function `myfunction.c':myfunction.c:(.text+0x7be): undefined reference to `dsyev_'
```

And several other such lines, all referring to similar missing references.

I have chased this error down to being something to do with BLAS. I followed the directions given at [this excellent link](http://bickson.blogspot.co.za/2011/02/installing-blaslapackitpp-on-amaon-ec2.html) for installing BLAS and put the relevant directory on the path. I also changed my Makefile accordingly to find these libraries.

Any help on this issue would be really appreciated!

Just to update, I recently installed itpp as well, also following the instructional [here](http://bickson.blogspot.co.za/2011/02/installing-blaslapackitpp-on-amaon-ec2.html), since it seemed my missing references were linked to that. No changes so far...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved! Hooray! I just danced around my office...

For those who have the same problem, here is what I did:

1) Follow the instructions given [here](http://bickson.blogspot.co.za/2011/02/installing-blaslapackitpp-on-amaon-ec2.html) to make the lapack and blas libraries. To paraphrase, for a scientific Linux 6 machine, they are:

```
wget http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack.tgz
tar xvzf lapack.tgz
cd lapack-3.3.0  //if version number changes, change here to the right directory
mv make.inc.example make.inc
```

2) Then (important bit, also recommended [here](http://bickson.blogspot.co.za/2011/02/installing-blaslapackitpp-on-amaon-ec2.html)):

edit make.inc and add -m64 -fPIC flag to fortran compiler options: FORTRAN, OPTS, NOOPT, LOADER

Then

```
make blaslib
make
```

Now, what you have is, in /lapack-3.6.1 (or whatever your directory is called after this process), two files:

librefblas.a , and liblapack.a.

3) The next thing I did was to copy librefblas.a and liblapack.a into some subdirectories - i.e. /lib/liblapack for liblapack.a and /lib/libblas for librefblas.a

4) Then, put those directories in your makefile, like this:

```
LIBDIR1 = /path/lib/lapack
LIBDIR2 = /path/lib/blas

LIBS =   -L$(LIBDIR1) -llapack  -L$(LIBDIR2) -lblas $(SYSLIBS)
LIBSMPI = -L$(LIBDIR1) -llapack -L$(LIBDIR2) -lblas  $(MPILIBS) $(SYSLIBS)
```

I also added /path/lib/lapack and /path/lib/blas onto my LD_LIBRARY_PATH (and PATH, just-in-case...)

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/lib/lapack:/path/lib/blas
export PATH=$PATH:/path/lib/lapack:/path/lib/blas
```

Then, go to wherever you Makefile is, and type

```
make
```

Yay yay yay!

By the way, with the latest version of lapack and blas, obtained in step 1), I compiled with gcc version 5.1.0 and the corresponding mpicc (openmpi 1.10.2).

Hope this helps someone else and shares the absolute delight.